# Homotopy Lifting Problem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology

$X, \tilde{X}$ are hausdorff, path connected spaces

$p:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ is a local homeomorphism

Under these assumptions we have the following lemma:

If $f:Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, and $Y$ is connected, f has at most one lift with respect to $p$, that is if $f_1$, $f_2$ are both lifts with respect to $p$, then $f_1 = f_2$ or there is no point in $Y$ where $f_1 = f_2$

---

I want to prove the following:

Let $a$, $b$ be homotopic paths in $X$ (so that in particular $a$, $b$ have the same starting and endpoints), via the homotopy $F:I \times I \rightarrow X$, and suppose that $f_t = F(.,t)$ each have lifts $\tilde{f_t}$ with respect to $p$ starting at some $\tilde{x_0} \in p^{-1}(a(0))$.

($I$ is $[0,1]$)

Then the paths $\tilde{f_t}$ are homotopic in $\tilde{X}$ and in particular have a common starting and endpoint.

Attempt:

So far I have been able to construct a lifted homotopy, $\tilde{F}:[0,\epsilon] \times I \rightarrow \tilde{X}$ via considering a neighbourhood of $\tilde{x_0}$, $U$ where $p$ is a homeomorphism, then reasoning that $F^{-1}(p(U))$ is open in $I \times I$ and contains ${0} \times I$, so that $[0,\epsilon] \times I \subset F^{-1}(p(U))$ and $F([0,\epsilon] \times I) \subset p(U)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Then I defined $\tilde{F} = p \restriction_{U}^{-1} \circ F \restriction_{[0,\epsilon]\times I}$ a lift of $F$ on the desired domain. We also have that $\tilde{F} \restriction_{{0}\times I} = \tilde{x_0}$

So I know that the set of all $\epsilon \in I$ such that a lift as constructed above exists is nonempty, and that each lift corresponding to such an $\epsilon$ is unique, so that any other lift is either a continuation or a restriction of this lift (that is any other lift on some domain $[0,\epsilon_1] \times I$ must agree with lifts on domains that are contained within this domain i.e. $\epsilon_2 < \epsilon_1$) , which follows by our lemma.

I have also been able to show that given such a lift, if $\epsilon < 1$, we can always construct a continuation of the lift, that is we can find a lift $\tilde{F'}:[0,\epsilon + h] \times I \rightarrow \tilde{X}$, where $h$ depends on $\epsilon$,  but don't have control over how much bigger the continuation of the lift is ($h$ is dependent on $\epsilon$). Which implies that if we can show $\sup A \in A$ , then $1 \in A$ and we are done.

I am stuck at this point, as I cannot show that $\sup A \in A$ necessarily.. I would be extremely grateful for any help

EDIT:
I should add I am talking about homotopy of paths all throughout this question, no "free" homotopies where endpoints of each path in the homotopy are different - In this case any lifted homotopy will have to be a homotopy of paths by virtue of the fact that $p$ is a local homeomorphism, and so the preimage of an endpoint is a discrete set.. so this isn't a major concern, what is the primary trouble is how to construct a valid lifted homotopy on all of $I \times I$

Comment: You remark that $F^{-1}(p(U))$ for some neighborhood $U\ni\tilde x_0$ contains $0\times I$. Why is this true? I there any reason a neighborhood on which p restricts to a homeomorphism should contain the entire lift of the path $F|_{0\times I}$?

Comment: Well, first note $\tilde{x_0} \in U$, now we have that $p(x_0) = F(0 \times I)$, as $F$ is a homotopy of paths and thus all $f_s(t) = F(t,s)$ have the same start and endpoints... now since $p(x_0) \in p(U)$, it should be clear that $F^{-1}(p(U))$ contains $0 \times I$, as $F^{-1}(p(U))$ contains $F^{-1}(p(x_0))$, which is $F^{-1}(F(0 \times I))$

Comment: I suppose it sounds strange when you say "should contain the entire lift of the path ..", but because $F(0 \times I)$ is really just a singleton, its not too odd

Answer (score 1):

If $\tilde{F}(., t) = \tilde{f}_t$ denotes the lifting then it suffices to check that $\tilde{F}$ is continuous into $\tilde{X}$.

Do it "horizontally" locally instead of "vertically" as you've been trying to do.

That is, pick a point $(0, t_0) \in I \times I$ and show that there exists an open set $W \subseteq I \times I$ such that $I \times \{ t_0 \} \subseteq W \subseteq I \times I$ such that $\tilde{F}|_{W}$ is continuous. We can now find a "universal" length (which you have been struggling with) doing it horizontally as follows:

Note that for each $\tilde{x} \in \tilde{f}_{t_0}(I \times \{ t_0 \}) = \tilde{F}(I \times \{ t_0 \}) = K$, there exists an open subset $U_{\tilde{x}}$ containing $\tilde{x}$ such that $p(U_{\tilde{x}})$ is open and $p|_{U_{\tilde{x}}}$ is a homeomorphism. Cover $I \times \{ t_0 \} \subseteq \cup_{\tilde{x} \in K} \tilde{f}_{t_0}^{-1}(U_{\tilde{x}})$ and use the Lebesgue covering lemma to find the length $l > 0$ such that if $J$ is an subinterval of $I$ of length at most $l$ then $J \times \{ t_0 \}$ is contained in some $\tilde{f}_{t_0}^{-1}(U_{\tilde{x}})$. We may as well assume that $l = 1/n$ for some positive integer $n$.

Now the rest is induction with argument similar to yours. First, $\tilde{F}$ is continuous when restricted to some small "vertical" neighborhood of the form $\{ 0 \} \times I_{t_0}$ containing $(0, t_0)$. Pick some $U_{\tilde{x}}$ (as above paragraph) such that $\tilde{F}([0, l] \times \{ t_0 \}) \subseteq U_{\tilde{x}}$. We may cut $I_{t_0}$ if necessary (by using continuity on the "vertical" nbdh $\{ 0 \} \times I_{t_0}$) so that $\tilde{F}(\{ 0 \} \times I_{t_0}) \subseteq U_{\tilde{x}}$. We have $[0, l] \times \{ t_0 \} \in F^{-1}(p(U_{\tilde{x}}))$, so by compactness of $[0,l] \times \{ t_0 \}$ we can fatten $[0,l] \times \{ t_0 \} \subseteq [0,l] \times J_{t_0} \subseteq F^{-1}(p(U_{\tilde{x}}))$ for some neighborhood $J_{t_0}$ of $t_0$. We may cut this further to assume that $J_{t_0} \subseteq I_{t_0}$ so that $\tilde{F}$ is continuous on the first vertical strip $\{0 \} \times J_{t_0}$. Now $\tilde{F} = (p|_{U_{\tilde{x}}})^{-1} \circ F$ on $[0,l] \times J_{t_0}$ by the "unique lifting" lemma that you cited (because both functions start at the same points on the vertical $\{ 0 \} \times J_{t_0}$. The RHS is clearly a continuous expression, so expresses $\tilde{F}$ as a continuous function on a neighborhood of $[0,l/2] \times J_{t_0}'$ where $J_{t_0}'$ is a compact interval containing $t_0$ of length $1/2$ that of $J_{t_0}$.

Now one simply inducts (go from continuity of $\tilde{F}$ on the strip $\{l \} \times J_{t_0}$ to continuity on $[l, l + l/2] \times T_{t_0}$ for some nondegenerate interval $T_{t_0} \subseteq J_{t_0}$ that could be smaller). Since this stops in finite steps (in at most $2n$ steps to be exact), this "cutting" of the intervals around $t_0$ doesn't pose any problem. The point is that our $l$ doesn't depend on "where" we are on the horizontal strip $I \times \{ t_0 \}$.

Comment: Apologies if I'm being hasty here - I haven't finished reading your entire solution, but when you say "First, $\tilde{F}$ is continuous when restricted to some small "vertical" neighbourhood of the form ${0} \times I_{t_0}$", surely since $\tilde{F}(0,t) = \tilde{x_0}$, by construction, we have in fact that $\tilde{F}$ is continuous when restricted to ${0} \times I$ , was this why you said $\tilde{F}$ is continuous when restricted to some small "vertical" neighbourhood of this form? Or were you using the fact that the neighbourhood was small somehow , perhaps later in the proof?

Comment: What you say is true, but ultimately one wants to get an induction argument going. For the next step, for example, you need to work with continuity of $\tilde{F}$ on a strip $\{ l/2 \} \times I_{t_0}$, because $\tilde{F}$ may not be continuous on $\{ l/2 \} \times I$. The "vertical" slices for $t_0$ will decrease, but the point is that it'll end in finite steps because of universality of $l$.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean - I'll leave future comments till after I've finished digesting the proof.

Comment: Given we have continuity of $\tilde{F}$ on the strip ${l} \times J_{t_0}$, isn't there some $U_{\tilde{x}}$ s.t. $\tilde{F}([l,2l]) \times t_0) \subset U_{\tilde{x}}$, and then proceeding as in paragraph 2, we should get a larger lift $\tilde{F}$ defined on $[0,2l] \times T_{t_0}$ for some smaller interval $T_{t_0}$ right? Why do we have to use steps of $l/2$?

Comment: That should work too. The organization using $l/2$ is from my laziness - but not an important feature of the proof.

Comment: And then I suppose at the end we can define the lift on $I \times I$ "vertical slice wise" ? And we have that everything remains well defined by the lemma I stated, (since all these lifts have to agree on $0 \times I$), and we finish off by showing continuity of this aggregate lift by appealing to the fact that each of these vertical slices are open, and so we can just use the pasting lemma? Oh - I should add, it should come WLOG if we make our slices open - which is what I think needs to be done to construct the aggregate lift.

Comment: Anyway - hopefully what I said above is what you had in mind, +1 for the solution :) I'm going to post a solution I happened to come up with in the time this question remained unanswered just for fun.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is needed. We would have already shown that the rough lift $\tilde{F}$ is actually continuous on all of $I \times I$ (being a local property) *jointly* in both variables.

Comment: Right, but doesn't the jointly in both variables thing implicitly use pasting? Because from what I understand being continuous jointly in both variables allows you to say that restrictions to little open rectangles centred at any point in $I \times I$ are continuous, so the whole thing is continuous by virtue of pasting

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the comment. We have $\tilde{F} : I \times I \to \tilde{X}$ already constructed with as $\tilde{F}(.,t) = \tilde{f}_t$. We checked that $\tilde{F}$ is continuous (not just on slices but on entirety of $I \times I \to \tilde{X}$), so $\tilde{F}$ provides (continuous) homotopy between the $\tilde{f}_t$'s. The crucial point is really that $\tilde{F} = (p|_{U_i})^{-1} \circ F$ on a suitable nbhd of a point $(x, t_0)$ with horizontal length $l$, which I think includes the confusion about the "pasting" thing. This is where the unique lifting property is used.

Comment: Yes, I mis-used the term slice, what I meant to say was that we have continuity on little open rectangles $I \times T_{t_0}$ in the domain, which gives us continuity on the whole domain.

Comment: Yep, that's what we're doing - continuity being a local property, sort of by checking continuity with "polaroid camera" coverings on each $I \times \{ t_0 \}$ (the compactness was needed to fatten this to an open subset $W$ of $I \times I$).